# Perl: split pages of each file into two

Tags: perl, pdf

I have written a code which should do the following:

1. If command line arguments != 1, then the script exits. If a filename as a command line argument is given, then the script splits this file.
2. If the 'go' command line argument is given, then the script gets the current directory, and then tries to split each pdf file in this directory. This procedure fails. I will give more details later.
3. If a command line argument is neither a filename nor 'go', then the script shows a suitable message.

As to the 2nd point, the errors read:

> Global symbol "$oldpdf" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\bin\current.pl line 21.
> Global symbol "$newpdf" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\bin\current.pl line 24.
> Global symbol "$oldpdf" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\bin\current.pl line 24.
> Global symbol "$newpdf" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\bin\current.pl line 31.
> Global symbol "$oldpdf" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\bin\current.pl line 31.
> Global symbol "$filename" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\bin\current.pl line 39.
> Global symbol "$newpdf" requires explicit package name at C:\strawberry\perl\bin\current.pl line 40.
> Execution of C:\strawberry\perl\bin\current.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

The script is as follows (I know it is ugly - I'm completely newbie):

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use PDF::API2;
use Cwd;

if ( @ARGV != 1 ) {
die "Command line should be either \"go\" or a filename!\n";
}

my $cmd = $ARGV[0];

if ($cmd eq "go") {
    my $current = getcwd();
    print "Current folder: $current\n";
    my @files = glob("*.pdf");
    foreach my $file (@files) {
        my $filename = $file;
        my $oldpdf = PDF::API2->open($filename);
        my $newpdf = PDF::API2->new;
}
for my $page_nb (1..$oldpdf->pages) {
my ($page, @cropdata);
 
$page = $newpdf->importpage($oldpdf, $page_nb);
@cropdata = $page->get_mediabox;
$cropdata[2] /= 2;
$page->cropbox(@cropdata);
$page->trimbox(@cropdata);
$page->mediabox(@cropdata);
 
$page = $newpdf->importpage($oldpdf, $page_nb);
@cropdata = $page->get_mediabox;
$cropdata[0] = $cropdata[2] / 2;
$page->cropbox(@cropdata);
$page->trimbox(@cropdata);
$page->mediabox(@cropdata);
}
 
(my $newfilename = $filename) =~ s/(.*)\.(\w+)$/$1-crop.$2/;
$newpdf->saveas("$newfilename");
}

elsif   (-f $cmd) {
    my $oldpdf = PDF::API2->open($cmd);
    my $newpdf = PDF::API2->new;
    for my $page_nb (1..$oldpdf->pages) {
    my ($page, @cropdata);
     
    $page = $newpdf->importpage($oldpdf, $page_nb);
    @cropdata = $page->get_mediabox;
    $cropdata[2] /= 2;
    $page->cropbox(@cropdata);
    $page->trimbox(@cropdata);
    $page->mediabox(@cropdata);
     
    $page = $newpdf->importpage($oldpdf, $page_nb);
    @cropdata = $page->get_mediabox;
    $cropdata[0] = $cropdata[2] / 2;
    $page->cropbox(@cropdata);
    $page->trimbox(@cropdata);
    $page->mediabox(@cropdata);
}
 
(my $newfilename = $cmd) =~ s/(.*)\.(\w+)$/$1-crop.$2/;
$newpdf->saveas("$newfilename");
}

else {
    print "Bad parameter!\n";
}
```

---

#### Updated

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDF::API2;
use Cwd;

if ( @ARGV != 1 ) {
    die "Command line should be either \"go\" or a filename!\n";
}

my $cmd = $ARGV[0];

if ( $cmd eq "go" ) {

    my $current = getcwd();
    print "Current folder: $current\n";
    my @files = glob("*.pdf");
    
    foreach my $file (@files) {

        my $filename = $file;
        my $oldpdf   = PDF::API2->open($filename);
        my $newpdf   = PDF::API2->new;
    }

    for my $page_nb ( 1 .. $oldpdf->pages ) {

        my ( $page, @cropdata );

        $page = $newpdf->importpage( $oldpdf, $page_nb );
        @cropdata = $page->get_mediabox;
        $cropdata[2] /= 2;
        $page->cropbox(@cropdata);
        $page->trimbox(@cropdata);
        $page->mediabox(@cropdata);

        $page        = $newpdf->importpage( $oldpdf, $page_nb );
        @cropdata    = $page->get_mediabox;
        $cropdata[0] = $cropdata[2] / 2;
        $page->cropbox(@cropdata);
        $page->trimbox(@cropdata);
        $page->mediabox(@cropdata);
    }

    ( my $newfilename = $filename ) =~ s/(.*)\.(\w+)$/$1-crop.$2/;
    $newpdf->saveas("$newfilename");
}

elsif ( -f $cmd ) {

    my $oldpdf = PDF::API2->open($cmd);
    my $newpdf = PDF::API2->new;

    for my $page_nb ( 1 .. $oldpdf->pages ) {
        my ( $page, @cropdata );

        $page = $newpdf->importpage( $oldpdf, $page_nb );
        @cropdata = $page->get_mediabox;
        $cropdata[2] /= 2;
        $page->cropbox(@cropdata);
        $page->trimbox(@cropdata);
        $page->mediabox(@cropdata);

        $page        = $newpdf->importpage( $oldpdf, $page_nb );
        @cropdata    = $page->get_mediabox;
        $cropdata[0] = $cropdata[2] / 2;
        $page->cropbox(@cropdata);
        $page->trimbox(@cropdata);
        $page->mediabox(@cropdata);
    }

    ( my $newfilename = $cmd ) =~ s/(.*)\.(\w+)$/$1-crop.$2/;
    $newpdf->saveas("$newfilename");
}

else {
    print "Bad parameter!\n";
}
```

Comment: Please, indent your code properly.

Comment: I've added a properly laid-out version of your program. I hope it's clear now what the problem is? I can't be certain exactly what you intended so I haven't  written a solution

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for this. I hope that I will now be more clear. I cannot deal with the following part: the script, when the 'go' command line argument is given should split each pdf in a current directory. The split procedure is in `elsif ( -f $cmd ) {` part and it works fine.

Comment: It's very simple. A hint — look at the program that I've formatted to see what you're doing in the `foreach my $file` loop

Comment: It's seems that I look but I don't see. The error is related to `Global symbol "$oldpdf" requires explicit package name` and I have googled this time of error but without luck.

Comment: @menteith All the stuff that needs to be within the scope of the loop... is not.

Comment: @menteith: Your loop `foreach my $file (@files) { ... }` uselessly assigns three variables and then ends. I'm sure you wanted to do something constructive inside that loop?

Comment: @Borodin. I'm stuck. Tried and tried but I can't deal with this. Could you correct the code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was trying to get at is that your loop

```
foreach my $file (@files) {

    my $filename = $file;
    my $oldpdf   = PDF::API2->open($filename);
    my $newpdf   = PDF::API2->new;
}
```

just sets the values of three variables and then discards them over and over again, once for each file. You're trying to use those values in the next loop

```
for my $page_nb ( 1 .. $oldpdf->pages ) { ... }
```

but by now `$oldpdf` no longer exists so the program dies

Here you go. I've added a few things, in particular I've put the process of splitting a file into a subroutine to avoid duplicating the code

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use PDF::API2;
use Cwd 'getcwd';

STDOUT->autoflush;

@ARGV == 1 or die qq{Command line should be either "go" or a filename!\n};

my ($cmd) = @ARGV;

if ( -f $cmd ) {
    split_file($cmd);
}
elsif ( lc($cmd) eq 'go' ) {

    printf "Current folder: %s\n", getcwd;

    split_file($_) for glob '*.pdf';
}
else {
    print "Bad parameter!\n";
}


sub split_file {

    my ($file) = @_;
    ( my $newfile = $file ) =~ s/(.+)\./$1-crop./x;

    printf qq{Processing "%s" => "%s"\n}, $file, $newfile;

    my $oldpdf = PDF::API2->open($file);
    my $newpdf = PDF::API2->new;

    for my $page_nb ( 1 .. $oldpdf->pages ) {

        for my $i ( 2, 0 ) {
            my $page      = $newpdf->importpage( $oldpdf, $page_nb );
            my @mediabox  = $page->get_mediabox;    # Left X, Bottom Y, Right X, Top Y
            $mediabox[$i] = $mediabox[2] / 2;
            $page->cropbox(@mediabox);
            $page->trimbox(@mediabox);
            $page->mediabox(@mediabox);
        }
    }

    $newpdf->saveas($newfile);
}
```

Comment: Dear @Borodin, thank you very much. I would have never came across a solution like yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a Perl error or warning that you don't understand, then you can always (temporarily) add `use diagnostics` to your code. This will give more details of the problem. In this case it will say something like this:

> (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates that all > variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or "state"), 
>   declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say which 
>   package the global variable is in (using "::").

Of course, you have made an effort to declare your variables with `my`, but it seems you haven't quite got the scoping right. Variables declared with `my` are scoped to only exist within the current block of code. So it seems that you are trying to use variables outside of the scope where they are declared.

Line 21 is this:

```
$page = $newpdf->importpage($oldpdf, $page_nb);
```

This uses both `$oldpdf` and $newpdf`. But neither of of these variables exist at this point. You declared them both within you`foreach my $file (@files) { ... }` block, but those declarations only have an effect inside that block. When you try to use the variables outside of that block, Perl (quite rightly) complains.

You need to think a little more deeply about where your variables are used and then you need to declare them in the correct scope.